# Converting PDF into text without losing the formatting

Tags: python, pdf, text, adobe, data-conversion

I want to convert a lot of **PDF files into txt files**. I have tried two different ways with python code. They work, but they files are very poorly formatted and I can't really use them later on.

I get a perfect result with great formatting when I use the "export as .txt" option in **Adobe Acrobat Reader**. Is there a way to use the Adobe Reader Function in a Python Program or "replicate" the way Acrobat converts a PDF?

The two results with suboptimal formatting come from **PDFMiner and PyPDF2.**

Comment: I've gotten pretty good results with [pdftotext](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/). Run `pip install pdftotext`

Comment: I wanted to try that. But I don't understand how to run it on Windows 10

Comment: looks like on windows you have to use a cmd line utility called [xpdf](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html) - you could put it in a powershell script. I'm not a windows user, sorry.